# Implement function over lists efficiently, instead of per-element

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a function, which takes the numeric values
`d1,d2,p1,p2,s`
as input, and should return:

- `{d1,d2}` if `d1 <= p1*s` and `d2 <= p2*s`
- `{d1,s-d1}` if `d1 <= p1*s` and `d2 > p2*s`
- `{s-d2,d2}` if `d1 > p1*s` and `d2 <= p2*s`
- `{p1*s,p2*s}` if `d1 > p1*s` and `d2 > p2*s`

An easy way to implement this function is the following:

```
f[d1_,d2_,p1_,p2_,s_] := Which[d1 <= p1*s && d2 <= p2*s, {d1,d2}, d1 <= p1*s && d2 > p2*s, {d1,s-d1}, d1 > p1*s && d2 <= p2*s, {s-d2,d2}, True, {p1*s,p2*s}]
```

However, instead of only calling this function for one set of values, I want to call this function for a list of values. Specifically, I have given a list `Px` that consists of pairs `{p1,p2}`, a list `Sx` that consists of values `s`, and a list `Dx` that consists of values `{d1,d2}`.

In an effort to make the implementation more efficient, I did the following:

```
checkCase = Thread[#[[1]] <= #[[2]]*#[[3]]] & /@ Transpose@{Dx, Sx, Px};
functionValue = Flatten[Which[
     #[[1]] == {True, True}, #[[2]], 
     #[[1]] == {True, False}, {#[[2]][[1]], #[[3]] - #[[2]][[1]]},
     #[[1]] == {False, True}, {#[[3]] - #[[2]][[2]], #[[2]][[2]]},
     True, #[[4]]*#[[3]]
     ] & /@ Transpose@{checkCase, Dx, Sx, Px}];
```

However, this is of course a very basic speed-up, just using the map-operator. I feel like there are is much more potential in speeding-up the above computation over the three lists, using vertorized operators, and would be very grateful if someone would be able to point out what functions and/or operators would be useful here.

Comment: You can use your function `f` on your lists by combing them and then `MapApply`ing. 

Eg: `Dx = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {3, 2}];
Px = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {3, 2}];
Sx = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 3];

input = Flatten /@ Thread[{Dx, Px, Sx}];
f @@@ input`

Comment: Perhaps [`BoolEval`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BoolEval/), written by our very own [@Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs), could be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With functions such as `UnitStep`, you can apply your condition in a `Listable` fashion to enjoy its performance, like below:

Here I chose 1 million random numbers for each column:

```
Block[{d1, d2, p1, p2, s, temp1, temp2, temp1not, temp2not, result1, 
  result2, result3, result4},

 {d1, d2, p1, p2, s} = RandomInteger[10, {5, 1000000}];

 temp1 = UnitStep[p1*s - d1];
 temp2 = UnitStep[p2*s - d2];
 temp1not = 1 - temp1;
 temp2not = 1 - temp2;
 
 result1 = Pick[Transpose@{d1, d2}, temp1*temp2, 1];
 result2 = Pick[Transpose@{d1, s - d2}, temp1*temp2not, 1];
 result3 = Pick[Transpose@{s - d2, d2}, temp1not*temp2, 1];
 result4 = Pick[Transpose@{p1*s, p2*s}, temp1not*temp2not, 1];
 
 ]

(* Out: {0.131124, Null} *)
```

Your function on similar data was around 4 times slower on my machine with Mathematica 13.3.1:

```
Block[{d = RandomInteger[10, {1000000, 5}]},
  f @@@ d;
  ] // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {3.84095, Null} *)
```

We can squeeze our code further if we `Pick` elements first before calculating the final expression like `s-d2, d2` or by using `Compile*` functions in Mathematica.

Since version 12.1, we can execute `Julia` directly from the notebook. In computation-intensive workflows, it's a good reference to compare. In this case, a similar approach was 5 times faster than the provided solution.

Here is the code in Julia:

```
using Random
n= 1000000
d1 = rand(Int, n)
d2 = rand(Int, n)
p1 = rand(Int, n)
p2 = rand(Int, n)
s = rand(Int, n)

temp1 = d1 .<= p1.*s
temp2 = d2 .<= p2.*s

i = temp1 .* temp2
result1 = [d1[i] d2[i]]

i = temp1 .* .!temp2
result2 = [d1[i] s[i]-d2[i]]

i = .!temp1 .* temp2
result3 = [s[i]-d2[i] d2[i]]

i = .!temp1 .* .!temp2
result4 = [p1[i].*s[i] p2[i].*s[i]]
```

The main part was executed in `0.021768` seconds (second run).